# Redirect all subdomains to their respective normal domain in htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, wildcard-subdomain

I am using WordPress Multiste on CyberPanel. The child sites have their own mapped domains. I need all wildcard subdomains redirecting to their respective regular domain (without www)

For example, I have following sites.
mainsite.com
site2.com
site3.com

Currently:
anything.site2.com redirects to mainsite.com . Similarly,
anything.site3.com redirects to mainsite.com

What I want is that:
anything.site2.com redirects to site2.com ,
anything.site3.com redirects to site3.com , and so on.

What code should I add to .htaccess so that wildcard subdomains are redirected as mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you want to match any requested host name inside any ".com domain", extract the base domain name from that and redirect any request to it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:.+)\.([^.]+\.com)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Update for the question you ask in the first comment to this answer:

Sure, you could repeat the rule for all TLDs that are relevant, but that is only necessary if you want to use *different* rules. If you are not interested in the TLD at all, then just use a wildcard:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:.+)\.([^.]+\.[^.]+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If you want to accept just certain TLDs, then do that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:.+)\.([^.]+\.(?:com)|(?:org)|(?:info))$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Or you can apply the rule just to specific domains:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:.+)\.(exampleA.com)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:.+)\.(exampleB.org)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:.+)\.(exampleC.info)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Some of the sites have TLDs other than .com like .org, .net, etc. Should I repeat the rule for the other TLDs? Thanks!

Comment: @TamseelAhmad I added an update to the question ...

Comment: The wildcard redirect rule worked like a charm. Thanks!